# Getting Error when login notification is enabled. + How can i get granted permissions to my application

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

Scenario is

Account Settings -> Security -> login notification is enabled.
requesting permissions for parameters[email & publish_stream].

First time i try to login in my site using facebook account i get notification regarding

1. Name New Device.
2. requested parameters.

if i Save Device & granted all requested permissions, app. works fine. Now after granting requested permission if i login from new device[system] facebook connect again will ask user for 'Name New Device'. now i got ERROR on click of both options and control is not redirected to my application.

The Error is: [An error may have occurred as part of the login process. You can close this window and try returning to the application, though it may ask you to login again. This is likely due to a bug in the application.], error snap is attached.

Any negative option[Don't Save, Not Allow] take me to the else part of if(response.session) where i get response.session NULL. After closing the error window i again clicked on the facebook login button, now facebook connect automatically gets the session and application works fine if i/user have granted requested permissions.

JavaScript code is given below:

```
FB.login(function(response)

{

if (response.session)
{
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
var name;
var email;
var firstName;
var lastName;
FB.api('/me', function(user)
{
    console.log('Good to see you, ' + user.name + '.');
    if(user != null)
    {
        name = user.name;
    email=user.email;
    firstName = user.first_name;
    middleName = user.middle_name;
    lastName = user.last_name;
    window.location.href='fbconnector.do?name='+name+'&email='+email+'
            first_name='+firstName+'&last_name='+lastName+'&middle_name='+middleName;
        }
});
}
else
{
    alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
}
}, {perms:'email, publish_stream'}
);
```